# UV Protection while trekking at 5000m for myopic vision

Tags: trekking, sunglasses, uv-protection

I have trouble seeing distant things and have myopia. Thus I prefer glasses with my prescription number (which is both cylindrical and spherical). I want protection from UV rays as I am going to spend some time during this trek which would be crossing 5000m. Can you suggest me specific kind of glasses that could help me. I read photochromatic lens might not be good enough. 
I don't want to change glass every time so I am looking to explain my local stores to get me a glass with specific properties that have my prescription for myopic vision.

Comment: [This answer](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/7785/2766) should help

Comment: Not really sure what you are wanting here. Most opticians should do prescription sunglasses with whatever your prescription is. You might also want to look at goggles that can go over your glasses depending on what you are doing.

Comment: I think you need to talk to an optometrist, and probably invest in a $1000 pair of shades.

Comment: For a trip where you'll spend a lot of time as high as 5000 m, goggles are probably the best option, because they will also protect your eyes from wind. But my usual solution is photochromatic glasses with cheap removable side shields. You can get a pair of glasses super cheap online from zennioptical.com. I use side shields sold as "sidewear" on amazon by a company called sideshield.com. You can even just use pieces of duct tape on the sides.

Answer (score 5):

There are several options

- Goggles that fit over you prescription glasses (Commonly referred to as "Over the glasses" or just 'OTG'.) - probably the cheapest solution, used successfully by many people.
- Contact lenses  are available for all sorts of prescriptions now days and could be worth considering.
- Prescription Sun Glasses - good wrap around sports len's will provide enough protection for 5000 Meters. These are expensive, but will be usable for other activities other than snow sports
- Prescription lens in Googles - best solution for above the snow line but not cheap and not as versatile as prescription sun glasses.

Talk to to your optometrist as he will be able to offer the best advise for you.